# Detecting memory access to a process

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to check if an application tries to manipulate a particular process (for ex. hooks itself to it). I couldn't find a proper approach to accomplish this. Is computing checksum over running process possible? If it's not how can i detect this situation?

Comment: You know the offending app? And you know how you to detect in your app manipultation occured?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get your question. I don't know how to detect manipulation so i have no idea of detecting manipulation occurrences. That's why i asked for help.

Comment: What is the actual goal you're trying to achieve? If you're trying to avoid/detect tampering in your own application, there's nothing that's going to work 100%.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm trying to protect a game application from hacking tools. Trying to detect manipulations over it.

Comment: @gcx: you should not trust client do all things who anyone can hack in server code, when you don't have server then why you want protect client, this is a single player game? (sorry for off topic this is rhetorical question)

Comment: @Svisstack: There isn't any hacking into server. There's a client which connects to server, and I'm writing a software that players install and uses with their client. The software's purpose is watch client application and do actions when players try to manipulate the client with hacking tools like speed hack (for example a program called Cheat Engine lets you speed up a particular process).

Comment: @gcx: ok you have right with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other process can't make hooks in your process, can modify memory but to make hooks this code must be in your address space, this can be done to injecting DLL to your process when is starting (at runtime inject dll is a hard one), you can easy check this by listing DLL's in your process and searching some `ReadProcessMemory`, `WriteProcessMemory`, `OpenProcess`, `CallNextHookEx` functions calls in their code. To do that get address ([`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) of function and search value in code (you can add some asm `call` predictions for that for tight range result).

**You can check what is wrong with your PE file in disk and in memory**, when DLL injection at startup time was occurrence then your PE file after was copied to memory from file should be corrupted, after last dll library you should have overwritten debug symbols with additional dll import. This modification can be done on file same as in memory.

The best method but probably will not easy for you when you are using C# language is **obfuscate your code**. I think this is a good method because **you don't hook something that you don't know how work**, because you don't know what hook you must do and where. But for good obfuscate C# code you must find good software for that and probably pay not low price.

Comment: @gcx: ReadProcessMemory, WriteProcessMemory will catch runtime injections too, runtime injection is from other process inject function to place when will be executed with load library code (in target memory not like hooks in target memory but calling function located in dll)

Comment: I see that you mentioned obfuscation. I think, you said that because of my "my process" referance. I referred a particular process by saying my process. I've edited the original post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Here's the best free obfuscator I know: [Eazfuscator.NET](http://www.foss.kharkov.ua/g1/projects/eazfuscator/dotnet/Default.aspx)

Comment: @ken2k Thank you, but the subject is not really about obfuscation.

Comment: @gcx Yes I know it's a bit off-topic, but Svisstack mentioned the fact that good obfuscators are not low price, so I mentioned Eazfusctoar which is free and actually very good.