# Detecting process memory injection on windows (anti-hack)

Tags: c++, windows, memory, code-injection

Standard hacking case. Hack file type injects into a started process and writes over process memory using WriteProcessMemory call. In games this is not something you would want because it can provide the hacker to change the portion of the game and give himself an advantage.

There is a possibility to force a user to run a third-party program along with the game and I would need to know what would be the best way to prevent such injection. I already tried to use a function EnumProcessModules which lists all process DLLs with no success. It seems to me that the hacks inject directly into process memory (end of stack?), therefore it is undetected. At the moment I have came down to a few options.

1. Create a blacklist of files, file patterns, process names and memory patterns of most known public hacks and scan them with the program. The problem with this is that I would need to maintain the blacklist and also create an update of the program to hold all avalible hacks. I also found this usefull answer [Detecting memory access to a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679280/detecting-memory-access-to-a-process) but it could be possible that some existing DLL is already using those calls so there could be false positives.
2. Using ReadProcessMemory to monitor the changes in well known memory offsets (hacks usually use the same offsets to achieve something). I would need to run a few hacks, monitor the behaviour and get samples of hack behaviour when comparing to normal run.
3. Would it be possible to somehow rearrange the process memory after it starts? Maybe just pushing the process memory down the stack could confuse the hack.
   This is an example of the hack call:

   WriteProcessMemory(phandler,0xsomeoffset,&datatowrite,...);

So unless the hack is a little more smarter to search for the actual start of the process it would already be a great success. I wonder if there is a system call that could rewrite the memory to another location or somehow insert some null data in front of the stack.

So, what would be the best way to go with this? It is a really interesting and dark area of the programming so I would like to hear as much interesting ideas as possible. The goal is to either prevent the hack from working or detect it.

Best regards

Comment: Common hacking tools usually will search for the number directly in the memory. Although it will incur some hit on the performance, can you store the stat that is likely to be hacked in an obfuscated form? And also create another "reference copy" which is obfuscated in a different way so that you will compare to know whether the value has been changed illegally?

Comment: I don't think so. The game itself cannot be changed and I can't obfuscate the values directly with my third-party program because it would most probably crash the game or at least confuse it.

Comment: Just to make sure there is no misunderstanding, I was suggesting a method for the game programmer to counter hack by making sure users using common utility has hard time modifying the memory. It won't work that well if the hack is done by specific tools, though.

Comment: IMO this would get better attention at http://security.stackexchange.com. Not sure though.

Comment: Just as a note, if the attacker has root on your system you will have no chance preventing him from manipulating an applications memory. The stuff you wrote lets me assume that you deploy some application and want to make sure that the user is not modifying it in runtime. The only way to improve that which still gives not too much security it by hashing the main values to some other memory location, but you can only do that if you know the mechanics of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Time after time compute the hash or CRC of application's image stored in memory and compare it with known hash or CRC.

Our service http://activation-cloud.com provides the ability to check integrity of application against the signature stored in database.